# iphone app delegate with logic + facebook connect?

Tags: iphone, facebook, delegates

i'm really stuck on this one so please help!

I'm writing an app that implements facebook connect so when the app starts, I need it to check to see if it has a valid facebook access token, AND also check if their appKey that i provide is still valid (i don't want more than 1 account logged in at a time).  so what needs to happen is..

App starts -> get facebook/my access key/token from NSUserDefaults -> send my appkey to a server to make sure it's still valid -> if valid then show my tableviewcontroller.

if it fails anywhere else(facebook access token isn't valid, or their appkey for my app isn't valid), then they will be taken to a View with the facebook connect button. after they login from there, they will be shown the tableviewcontroller

I don't know how to structure my app delegate and view controllers for this to work.  From what I know about the facebook connect, most of the stuff has to happen in the delegate because facebook's application:handleOpenUrl: and fbDidLogin methods have to be called in the app delegate but if i do a

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tableController
```

or

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.loginButtonViewController
```

before that, then i won't have access to these methods

Do i need to put in a delegate or something from the view controller back to the app delegate? i have no clue..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"MY_APP_ID"];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
NSString *myKey;
if ([defaults stringForKey:@"myKey"]) {
    myKey= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[defaults stringForKey:@"myKey"]];
}
else{
    myKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
}
//SEND THE KEY + FBID TO SERVER
if ([facebook isSessionValid] /*&& [response==OK]*/) {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    //delegate data to EventsTableController
}
else{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.loginController;
}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSLog(@"did login");
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSString *myKey;
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
if ([defaults stringForKey:@"myKey"]) {
    myKey= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[defaults stringForKey:@"myKey"]];;
}
else{
    myKey= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
}
//NSString *validKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"OK"];
//Send myKey and validKey to server
//server will do its thang and send data

[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What means myKey?
In facebook.h, the method `isSessionValid` uses only two variables. (accessToken, expirationDate)

```
- (BOOL)isSessionValid {
  return (self.accessToken != nil && self.expirationDate != nil
       && NSOrderedDescending == [self.expirationDate compare:[NSDate date]]);
}
```

You should have moved above code to RootViewController.m not AppDelegate.m
Because MainWindow.xib can recognize only one RootView.
(In your case, you wanted to have more RootView, navController, loginController)
[See this Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html)

So, I suggest that you move your authorization code to RootViewController.m
(etc. viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods)
Next, in RootViewController, try to change your view according to whether session is valid or not.

And try Again! It will work!

Comment: thanks for the reply! i wasn't sure if the facebook connect worked in the rootviewcontroller.  i'll try it and let you know!

Comment: It should work. If you add "FBconnect.h" in you rootviewcontroller.h

Comment: I was able to get the facebook login to work! i was missing the facebook.sessionDelegate=self; and also needed to change a line in the Facebook.m file.  thanks!